# How to start PostgreSQL server on Ubuntu 14.04 installed using homebrew

Tags: django, postgresql, ubuntu, server, homebrew

I am trying to connect my Django Application with `PostgreSQL`, and it installed it using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/). My installation is successful, as you see:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5
```

For installation I am following the guide from here [link](https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Guides/blob/master/all/install_postgresql_mac_&_linux.md). According to this guide, once your installation is complete then run the following command to start your server.

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

When I run the first command, it is showing me an error:

```
ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/rakesh/Library/LaunchAgents’: No such file or directory
```

Then When I run the second command it is showing me `launchctl: command not found`

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
launchctl: command not found
```

There is another option to run the command in the guide: `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` but when I do this:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
postgres cannot access the server configuration file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

I spent a lot of time already on this and want someone to help me. Could you please tell me, why my postgreSQL server not running, and how do that?

When I try to do run `psql` command:

```
>psql
>psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Comment: Homebrew is for OSX primarily (I thought exclusively until just now) ...did you use this https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew ?  why not just use Ubuntu's own built in `apt get` ?   I assume all the instructions you get after installing a package with linuxbrew will still be targetted at OSX users, hence your problem trying to use `launchctl`, an OSX utility

Comment: try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: my suggestion is to use http://apt.postgresql.org

Comment: I resolved the issue by using `apt-get`. `Linuxbrew` is not working :/

Comment: And if I would use linuxbrew install postgres? how to start automatically the service?